# running a virtual machine with Cent-OS but problems occur

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, vmware

I have a windows 7 OS on my desktop and I have VMware Player installed. I did not use easy install when I created a VM that has Cent-OS installed. When I reboot the VM, I tend to get stuck in this terminal instead of some GUI login:

[image]

I did log in and it is only a Linux terminal.
Is there a way to fix this??

Thank you!

Comment: Did you install a desktop environment during the OS install? If so, have you tried `startx` after logging in?

Comment: @dartonw I did type startx in the command and the terminal responded 'command not found' I am trying to follow this guide but no progress: http://blog.nowherelan.com/2013/12/24/install-a-desktop-environment-on-centos-minimal-install/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to install GNOME Desktop. Therefore, if you want a desktop environment in Cent-OS, you need to install the GNOME Desktop. I selected minimal install(big mistake) and the proper one with the Desktop UI environment is GNOME Desktop installation. I hope this will help someone's first time installing Cent-OS :)

Also, this can maybe benefit someone: http://blog.nowherelan.com/2013/12/24/install-a-desktop-environment-on-centos-minimal-install/